# Ubuntu freezes on boot at /tmp mount prompt

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox, freeze

I'm running an x86 Xubuntu guest on an x64 Windows 8 host using VirtualBox.  I managed to install Xubuntu and get some updates on the virtual machine, but after I rebooted for the first wave of updates I hit [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUldL.png) screen on boot.  If you can't see the image it states "The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present", and prompts the user to either skip with S or manually mount with M

I've found that [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1724209) (post #4) should solve the problem for most people, but attempting to input any command at all causes the OS to freeze completely.  The VirtualBox process drops to almost no CPU usage, and the only options are rebooting or REISUB.  I cannot advance past this screen, no matter what I've tried.  I want to know if there's some way to fix this problem before that screen on boot

Additional notes: I'd also like to add that I've had the same exact problem with Ubuntu versions 11.10 and 12.04, as well as on Xubuntu version 12.04 (all x86). After going through several excruciating and failed installation processes, I just want to use Ubuntu

UPDATE: For seemingly no reason at all, I managed to skip the aforementioned screen by pressing any key; this is strange because every other time I booted the VM it would freeze at this point. I proceeded to use my knowledge of this problem to ensure that my filesystem was read-write (apparently the "/tmp is not ready" screen appears when your filesystem is read-only). However, the second time I rebooted the VM for updates and installation changes I am facing the same problem all over again. I cannot advance past that frozen screen

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F3 and login into the shell.

Do ls -ld /tmp. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: drwxrwxrwt.

If not, do sudo chmod a+wt /tmp and check again (i.e. Ctrl+Alt+F7 and try a login).

This worked for me.

( Solution borrowed from --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop )

Bacchylides (5th century BC) said (in free English translation): "Everyone is wise due to the other, and in the past and now."

Answer (score -1):

Did you try ?:
Boot into recovery or telint ...

update-grub
update-initramfs

Need to read the log files ... inside VM too ...